# Is there any way to save alsamixer settings other than alsactl store?

Tags: sound, alsa, spdif

The root problem: for some reason, on boot, Ubuntu 14.04 disables (mutes) the S/PDIF output on my sound card.

[This question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings) indicate that `sudo alsactl store` will store the alsamixer settings once I've unmuted the S/PDIF output, but on boot, the S/PDIF output is muted again.

In `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/E4h3ECta)) there is one PDIF entry, which I've set to "true" and saved; this has resulted in solving auto-mute for my "Phantom Jack" but there's no other entry for the "true" S/PDIF in asound.state that I can manually adjust.

There's also an empty `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state.lock` file (11 bytes, blank in gedit) in the `/alsa/` directory. Is this something I should be dealing with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same problem on my pc:
 It appears that effectively alsa restores  SPDIF "unmuted" state during boot, but then  pulseaudio mutes it when user session  starts.
To verify that alsa restore is ok,  just run `sudo alsactl restore` in a terminal and look if it  unmute SPDIF.
To verify that pulseaudio is the problem , just run `pulseaudio -k` to relaunch pulseaudio : you should see that SPDIF is muted.

As I don't know how to set pulseaudio for not muting, this is a workaround inspired from [there](https://forums.mageia.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=5054)  :

- Try if this command unmutes SPDIF channel:
  `amixer set IEC958 unmute`
- If yes, create .unmute hidden file  :
  `gedit .unmute`
  paste 4 lines in it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sleep 10 
  /usr/bin/amixer set IEC958 unmute 
  exit
  ```

save and close.
Now, edit `.profile` file :
 `gedit .profile`
add this line at the end:

```
bash .unmute &
```

save and close.

Now test reopening session or rebooting .

**Note**: in the above link from Mageia, they use /etc/rc.local to run `alsactl restore` at boot time , it is also ok.   But using `.profile` and amixer, no need to "sudo" and it will unmute  at every session start for your login.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted [@laugeo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/549939/527764) to fix the problem with my headphones.

The problem was that the headphone was set to unmute but it was on 00 volume.

I wanted it to be 100, so I added this: `/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 set Headphone playback 100% unmute`

And the `.unmute` script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10 
/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 set Headphone playback 100% unmute
exit
```

If you want to unmute and set volume to 100% just change the channel. For example for master channel:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10 
/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 set Master playback 100% unmute
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run `sudo alsactl store` it gives me the following error

```
alsactl: get_controls:567: snd_ctl_open error: Invalid argument.
```

I needed to unmute the Master channel using

```
amixer set Master 100 unmute
```

and it worked perfectly for currently selected sound card. But the Master channel was always muted again after boot, so I created a script named `unmute.sh` and set `chmod 700` so that other users couldn't run it. I filled the script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
amixer set Master 100 unmute
```

and saved it to `~/.kde/Autostart` directory. If you have Kubuntu or other distro with KDE all scripts in that directory will be run on boot automatically.

If you don't have KDE you can try to add the `amixer` command to `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after trying everything else; in term -

```
sudo nautilus
```

open /etc/pulse/default.pa

hash out (add a #) to the beginning of the line reading 
**module-device-restore**

```
alsamixer
```

un-mute volume marked (M) use left / right keys to select, up down to adjust levels.

```
sudo reboot
```

This worked for me; copied from here; [Arch linux forum](https:////bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1450152#p1450152)

Good luck - hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works for me after trying lots of other solutions :

1. (root) open /et/pulse/default.pa
2. add a # at the beginning of the line that contains module-device-restore
3. set alsamixer properly unmuting all

4 reboot

many thanks !

hp600     debian 11.7