# Sound problem in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, alsa, 15.04, headphones

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 from a bootable pen-drive. When I start my machine, I get no sound on my headphone. To get around, I go to the terminal and type `alsamixer` and unmute the headphone from MM to 00. It works fine but I have to do the same each time I log in to my machine.

Comment: Consider taking a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings

Comment: It worked just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow after the system log in:

1. Open terminal and type `alsamixer`.
2. Unmute the `Headphone` entry pressing `m` once.
3. Save the alsamixer output by running `sudo alsactl store` in the terminal.
4. Save the mixer settings into a custom file with `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store` command. This command will store/clone a copy of the `asound.state` file from the `/var/lib/alsa/` directory to `~/.config/`.
5. Create a `.desktop` file by running `sudo nano ~/.config/autostart/alsarestore.desktop` and paste the following in.

   `[Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Name=alsarestore
   Exec=alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore`
6. Save the file by `Ctrl`+`x` and responding to any query that pops up.
7. Restart your machine and you should be *OK* with your sound.

I found the solution from the thread cited in the first comment. Grabbed the information together from different answers to make it clearer.

I am not sure whether the answer should apply to even slightly different problems from mine.

**Notes:**

1. `.config` is a hidden folder in your home folder. Use `Ctrl`+`h` to let the hidden files show up.
2. If the `autostart` folder does not exist in `.config` folder, create it manually or through terminal. I did not have `autostart` folder and I had to create.
3. Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Saved my life. How could a developer write a line of code without music on headphones. I should be the one of top features of installation to check :)

Comment: No `headphone` entry in alsamixer  in 16.10 :(