# USB Phillips Headphone

Tags: usb, headphones

I have installed on my box ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and im trying to use a Phillips USB headphone, but it simply don't work, don't even appear on the sound preferences.

How can i fix this issue and have it working properly ?!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and I don't remember now how did to solve this issue.
But have you tried with this solution
[Headset undetected when plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184901/headset-undetected-when-plugged-in)

In other case, if this not work.
Could you try with this another solution to a similar problem :)

[Headphones no longer detected in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768201/headphones-no-longer-detected-in-16-04)

Have fun !

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate please flag it as such instead.