# Mute headphones for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. I have to set option "HeadPhone" in AlsaMixer each time I start Ubuntu, otherwise I cannot get any voices from my earphones. And option "Headphone" in AlsaMixer resets every time I enter Ubuntu as depicted in the attached image.

How do I set it to stay unmuted?

[image: Mute "Headphone" on entering Ubuntu]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings