# No audio output in 18.04. Only output device is 'dummy output'

Tags: 18.04, sound, chromebook

[edit: Wasn't able to solve this, using a different distro now. Don't bother commenting on the question. Thank you guys for all your help.]

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP Chromebook 15. (Not through Crouton or anything, really installed Ubuntu.) No audio is output through my internal speakers, nor external, nor headphones. The only output device in my list is 'dummy Output'. Any help would be much appreciated. Please tell me if you need any hardware info, I'd be happy to provide it. While I am aware that this question has been asked before, none of the answers I found helped.

Here are a couple links to solutions I've already tried:

[Fix no sound dummy output issue](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)

[Sound card shown as dummy output in ubuntu 18 04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059619/sound-card-shown-as-dummy-output-in-ubuntu-18-04)

[Ubuntu 18.04 dummy output and sound disappeared](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/ubuntu-18-04-dummy-output-and-sound-disappeared-4175659386/)

[Persistent dummy output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output/800280#800280)

[Dummy output instead of audio device on debian 9](https://superuser.com/questions/1312163/dummy-output-instead-of-audio-device-on-debian-9)

Restarting ALSA didn't help, and attached is a picture of what happens when I run 'alsamixer' in the terminal. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZrdb.png)

The output of pacmd list-cards is as follows:

```
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd112c000 irq 126"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d71"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Is this a lost cause? Should I just reinstall ChromeOS?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. It helps to provide links to the answers you've already tried so we don't go suggesting things you've already done. Thanks.

Comment: For example, did you already try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800280/167115)

Comment: @mchid Got it. Give me a moment to go through some links and add to the post.

Comment: No problem. Another thing, did you install `pavucontrol` which shows up as "pulseaudio volume control" in your installed applications? This is usually step one as you may need this later. Additionally, I noticed only HDMI shows up. Sometimes, you can plug an HDMI cable in and unplug it to refresh the devices.

Comment: @mchid Yes, I have installed pavucontrol. I'll do what you suggested momentarily. Should I make sure that the HDMI cable is connected to some other output, or does that not matter?

Comment: I don't think it needs to be connected on the other end but if that doesn't work, it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I (somehow) just noticed that my device doesn't have an HDMI output (even though I swore it did). Sorry about that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you may be missing an `asound.state` file or there may be a custom version of this file that could make your audio work.

Comment: I tried generating that file with ```alsactl store```, which created the file, but changed nothing.

Comment: I found an answer that talks about the file. However, I suggest backing up your original existing `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` file before you try the fix just in case. [There is an answer that deals with this here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974073/no-audio-on-acer-chromebook-14-under-ubuntu-17-10). They say you can get the file from a copy of galliumOS or you can probably copy the `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` file from ChromeOS if you still have access to it.

Comment: The one you generated probably isn't correct but the one from GalliumOS or from ChromeOS supposedly has the correct configuration.

Comment: Alternatively, the [linked GalliumOS file referenced in the answer](https://pastebin.com/c4qU9hdg) may work for you as this is the one for GalliumOS which should theoretically be the same for all Chromebooks.

Comment: Again, I would make a backup before replacing any file. There is also a GalliumOS `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file [here on github](https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-baytrail/blob/master/etc/pulse/default.pa) that some people have had success with. Additionally, a misconfigured `default.pa` is often responsible for "dummy output" problems. Reboot after replacing the file.

Comment: Just FYI: The sound output over Display Port is also called HDMI.

Comment: Check out https://askubuntu.com/a/1469281/124466. Sound works on native installations of Ubuntu beyond version 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel`, if it says

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel not found in directory /lib/modules...
```

then you're missing the linux-modules-extra package containing these. I think it was introduced somewhere between kernel 4 and 5. If so, then this might help

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```