# No audio output on Ubuntu 21.10, Dell Latitude 14 1404 Rugged

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell

Audio on Windows works perfectly, no issues. No option in BIOS to disable.

Speakers are not muted in GUI or in Alsamixer, though Alsamixer pulls up HDA Intel HDMI first, but when switching to HDA Intel PCH nothing changes.

I have installed, updated, uninstalled, disabled and enabled PulseAudio

Output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
    Memory at f7c34000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
--
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at f7c30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

Any ideas? I think I've read every forum post related to this computer and audio in general, and still hit a wall.

Comment: I have had similar issues with Linux on various Chromebooks. It is a pain in the butt. Look over this, it may have a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974073/no-audio-on-acer-chromebook-14-under-ubuntu-17-10 Yes, I know it says Chromebook, but the commands work on all of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will help a Latitude but add this parameter to the kernel  command line:

```
snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=3
```

I had to do this on a Dell Venue Pro 11 and the sound worked perfectly.
It is for kernels after 5.10 as a change was made to the drivers.
Source: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SofDefaultForIntelLpe

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228322)