# sound not working on 17.10 fresh install

Tags: sound, 17.10

I installed ubuntu 17.10 on a new laptop today. The sound is not working at all. Tried restarting and a few commands but doesn't seem to help. Was working fine on live cd mode(usb)

tried:

```
pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

not sure if this helps to debug:

```
aplay -l outputs
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Is maybe your output muted? Try installing `pavucontrol` and try changing settings there (such as muting/unmuting).

Comment: @TomášPospíšek it's not; that was the first thing I checked

Comment: In principle you should be able to boot from the live cd, save the alsa settings like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings (`sudo alsactl store`) and then copy the saved settings to your installed Ubuntu and load them there. If it's only some weird setting, then that should restore sound on the installed Ubuntu.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek will try it