# Ubuntu 20.04: Earphones don't output any sound after ubuntu-restricted-extras installation

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones, ubuntu-restricted-extras

- **Environment**: Fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron 5567 laptop.
- **Related softwares installed**: VLC and FFmpeg installed (haven't had any problems with these)
- **Problem**: Sound doesn't come out of the earphones.
- **Recent changes to the system**: Installed ubuntu-restricted-extras.
- **Further details**: Sound works on in-built speakers. On earphones, when sound supposed to come there's a one-time faint *pop* sound comes. And that's it. It detects as headphone and shows it emits sound on settings and it shows sounds are working on the scale. [image attached]
- **Special note**: Everything works normally and sounds working on same earphones, same laptop on Ubuntu 20.04 live session.
- **Tried solutions**: Removing ubuntu-restricted-extras didn't fix the problem. Tried to fix it on `alsamixer` no luck. `pulseaudio` shows the same results as the sound settings shows.

PS: Reinstalling the OS isn't an option right now.

[Attached: Screenshot of the sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFikN.png)

Comment: have you tried running `alsactl restore` afterplugging in headphones

Comment: @ptetteh227 thank you very much, it worked.

Comment: @ptetteh227 is there a way I can make this permanent? Because every time I start over after sleep or shutdown, it needs to restore again to make it work.

Comment: Please try this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings  and this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/alsactl.1.html or even this https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/storing-alsamixer-settings/16953

Comment: Thanks a lot again. `sudo alsactl store` worked.

Comment: alright. let me make it into an answer so it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a temporary fix Run

```
alsactl restore
```

after plugging in headphones

to make it persistent so it survives a reboot run

```
sudo alsactl store
```

Answer (score 0):

Install "pulseaudio volume control"
`sudo apt install pavucontrol`
Launch it from menu or using "pavucontrol" command.

- In "pulseaudio volume control"    configuration tab, check "profile" is  analog.
  In output device tab, test changing port to "headphone" or "speaker". Click the green button near "internal audio"  .
  2 commands to reset pulseaudio config:
  `mv .config/pulse .config/pulsebak

  killall pulseaudio`
- In alsamixer, check  that "headphone" and "speaker" faders are muted and unmuted when connecting/disconnecting jack.
- Another  post  indicates this fix :  disable audio in bios, then enable again
- if dualboot, disable fastboot in windows.

Comment: The solution given by @ptetteh worked while this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to ubuntu focal fossa 20.04 from 18.04 and suddenly the sound and the mic stopped working.

As I am a beginner , I wasn't able to make correct changes in the alsa mixer . The other solutions in this post didn't work for me.

So, I use the following command to add the GUI version of the alsa tools.
This can be done by the following commands:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui

hdajackretask
```

after this use the override option corresponding to the headphone and check the override option and apply changes.

If it works now, again reboot and check. In case , it doesn't work after reboot, you can use the Install boot override.

Comment: Accepted answer worked for me. I think you were experiencing something else. But anyway thanks for the response.