# How can I prevent pulseaudio from overriding alsamixer settings?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.04

after updating to 22.04 from 20.04 I had no sound at all. After unmuting "Front" in `alsamixer` I can hear sound as I'm used to. However after shutting down and rebooting settings are back to default.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Device: HDA ATI SB

Chip: Realtek ALC892

I tried different stuff, for example as stated here: [Howto save AlsaMixer settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings)

```
sudo alsactl store
```

and also

```
alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store
```

followed by

```
alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore
```

Also tried this https://dev.to/luisabianca/fix-alsactl-store-that-does-not-save-alsamixer-settings-130i
which got me close to a solution, however I need to start the terminal in every session to restore alsamixer settings.

I also found out, pulseaudio is actually overriding alsamixer settings since `pulseaudio -k` resets alsamixer settings even if I changed them manually before.

Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change the permissions to read? No idea if that is allowed but you can always revert that ;)

Comment: Tried that by changing rights of `/var/lib/asound.state` through `sudo chmod u=r,g=r,o=r asound.state`. Still calling `pulseaudio -k` overrides the settings I just set before.