# Sigmatel sound card not working on an Dell XPS m2010

Tags: 11.04, sound, drivers, usb, dell

I've installed Ubuntu 11.4 on my dell xps m2010 using wubi. Then booted up and could not connect to the Internet using  `3three huawei e122 usb mobile broadband` (I would like this to work also).

I've managed to connect through a wireless network, I went to my favorite sites and was told I needed to install adobe flash player.This what I did players run and picture is good. But there is no sound!

Then I've tried to play songs in Banshee, but no sound.

I have checked everything in sound preferences including test speaker, there is sound. I have `sigmatel sound card`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for your Huawei Modem, take a look at this: [How do i configure huawei usb modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31875/how-do-i-configure-huawei-usb-modem/31887#31887) and this: [How do I set up an MTS MBlaze modem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16935/how-do-i-set-up-an-mts-mblaze-modem/41892#41892)

For your sound issues take a look at this: [Sound does not work once my profile loads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23616/sound-does-not-work-once-my-profile-loads/23761#23761) and this: [Howto save AlsaMixer settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings/50093#50093)

If you need further details please drop a comment and I will edit this.

Good luck!